# The same Parsing-Pattern for String to Date works once and the other time it fails?

Tags: parsing, datetime, powershell

I download my emails and want to sort them acc. to their date. Some of them are forwarded so that the email date is the forwarding date but nit the original date.

So here are parts of the forwarded email:

+OK 5522 octetsReturn-Path: ... id lg7sm19095682wjb.9.2014.08.01.01.02.00 ...
cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);  ...
Fri, 01 Aug 2014 01:02:00 -0700 (PDT)Message-ID:...
**Date: Fri, 01 Aug 2014 10:02:04** +0200From: ... 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowedContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
-------- Original-Nachricht -------- ....
**Datum:    Tue, 22 Oct 2013 18:18:18** +0200 (CEST)Von: ...

If I try to catch the original email date (**Date: Fri, 01 Aug 2014 10:02:04**)
this match and parse works perfectly!!

```
            # **real send date** of email: Date: Fri, 01 Aug 2014 10:02:04 +0200
            if ( $mail -match 'Date:\W[a-zA-Z]+\W+(\d+.+?\d{4}\W[\d:]+)\W' ) { 
                $a=[datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1], "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null)
                } else { $listOfMails.Add($a.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH:mm:ss"),$mail); $n--; continue }
            } else { $n--; continue }
```

But exactly this fails if I try to match and parse the original date of the email?

```
            # the original date of the email:  Datum:   Tue, 22 Oct 2013 18:18:18...
            if ( $mail -match 'Original-Nachricht.+?Datum\W*[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\W+(\d+.+?\d{4}\W[\d:]+)\W*' ) {
                Write-Host "Date 1: >$($Matches[1])<"
                try {
                    $a=[datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1], "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null) 
                } catch { $_; break }
                $listOfMails.Add($a.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH:mm:ss"),$mail); $n--; continue }
            }
```

1) Well the match is correct ($true)!
2) Write-Host prints:  Date 1: >22 Oct 2013 18:18:18< 
3) To me the correct pattern to parse would be: 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss' 
4) but it fails??
5) The Error-message of PowerShell:
Exception.. "The string wasn't reconized as as a valid DateTime" (my translation from German)
Bei C:\Users\cas\Documents\sysTools\PC\WindowsPowerShell\Pop3_v2.ps1:168 Zeichen:50
+                         $a=[datetime]::ParseExact <<<< ($Matches[1], "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null) 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Any idea what causes the problem and what to do?
Thanks

PS just let me add the this message was directly dld from the mail box and then parsed..

Found the solution on my German PC the engl. Oct causes the problem - Okt solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the culture. From MSDN, when you call DateTime.ParseExact:

> If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used.

I am assuming that your parsing fails because you are using the German `CultureInfo` `de-DE`. The same parsing works well with `en-US` or the `InvariantCulture`.

```
PS C:\> $s = "22 Oct 2013 18:18:18"
PS C:\> $f = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
PS C:\> [datetime]::ParseExact($s, $f, [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [datetime]::ParseExact("22 Oct 2013 18:18:18", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", [CultureI ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

PS C:\> [datetime]::ParseExact($s, $f, [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-US"))

Tuesday, October 22, 2013 18:18:18

PS C:\> [datetime]::ParseExact($s, $f, [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

Tuesday, October 22, 2013 18:18:18
```

I don't know German so I went on Google Translate and found that "October" in German is spelled "Oktober". Now, the following code works:

```
PS C:\> [datetime]::ParseExact("22 Okt 2013 18:18:18", $f, [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))

Tuesday, October 22, 2013 18:18:18
```

Comment: thanks but now I get another error: The Typ [CultureInfo] could not be found... It seems I have available only de-AT. My google search only shows me how to set (another) culture - but how can I use more than one?

Comment: As this problem is only because of the month's name I made a hash ={Jan=1;Feb=2;..} and use it: $($month.$($Matches[2])). This way I can even mix German and English: @{.. May=5;Mai=5;..Oct=10;Okt=10;..}

Comment: Regarding the "Type [CultureInfo] could not be found" error, try to use the fully qualified name of the class `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture`. And you should have access to the InvariantCulture, which is what you should use.